# Extracción de caracteristicas con IDs de tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api, tweepy

Estoy tratando de extraer la información de un tweet de una ID. Con la ID, quiero obtener la fecha de creación del tweet, el tweet, locación, seguidores, amigos, favoritos, descrición de su perfil, si esta verificado y el idioma, pero estoy teniendo problemas para realizarlo. A continuación, mostrare los pasos que sigo para llevar acabo lo que quiero.

He realizado el siguiente código. Para empezar, tengo las IDs de los tweets en un archivo txt y los leo de la siguiente forma:

```py
# Lectura de archivo txt
txt = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Mini-proyecto Texto/archivo.txt'
with open(txt) as archivo:
  lines = archivo.readlines()
```

Después, agrego cada uno de los IDs a una lista:

```py
# Agregar las IDs a una lista
IDs = []
for i in lines:
  IDs.append(i.rsplit())
  #print(i.rsplit())

IDs
#[['1206924075374956547'],
# ['1210912199402819584'],
# ['1210643148998938625'],
# ['1207776839697129472'],
# ['1203627609759920128'],
# ['1205895318212136961'],
# ['1208145724879364100'], ...
```

Por último, empiezo a extraer la información que requiero de la siguiente forma:

```py
# Extraer información de los tweets
tweets_df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in IDs:
  try:
    info_tweet = api.get_status(i, tweet_mode="extended")  
  except:
    pass

  tweets_df2 = tweets_df2.append(pd.DataFrame({'ID': info_tweet.id,
                                             'Tweet': info_tweet.full_text,
                                             'Creado_tweet': info_tweet.created_at,
                                             'Locacion_usuario': info_tweet.user.location,
                                             'Seguidores_usuario': info_tweet.user.followers_count,
                                             'Amigos_usuario': info_tweet.user.friends_count,
                                             'Favoritos_usuario': info_tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                             'Descripcion_usuario': info_tweet.user.description,
                                             'Verificado_usuario': info_tweet.user.verified,
                                             'Idioma': info_tweet.lang}, index=[0]))
  tweets_df2 = tweets_df2.reset_index(drop=True)


tweets_df2
```

La siguiente imagen es la salida de la variable tweets_df2, pero no entiendo porque se repiten los valores una y otra vez. ¿Alguien sabe que tengo de mal en el código?

Si necesitan el txt les proporciono el link del drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vyohQMpLqlKqm6b4iTItcVVqL2wBMXWp/view?usp=sharing

[image: Salida de la variable tweets_df2]

De antemano, muchas gracias por su tiempo :3

Comment: ¿No te estará dando algún tipo de excepción la api que no estás manejando porque simplemente estás poniendo `pass`? Convendría capturar la excepción e imprimirla para ver si algo está ocurriendo. No es nada recomendable ponerle a una excepción `pass`, te estás poniendo tu mismo una venda en los ojos y ocultándote lo que puede estar pasando. Te digo mi teoría. La `api` te está dando constantes errores que no ves porque le tienes puesto `pass`. Luego cuando sale del `pass` como `info_tweet` sigue siendo el mismo valor, lo agrega una y otra vez al dataframe.

Comment: Lo otro que puedes hacer, es mover el código donde agregas datos al dataframe para dentro del `try`. Si por casualidad la petición dió un error, no va a agregarte los datos de la petición anterior, seguirá a la siguiente sin agregar nada.

Comment: Considera también que si estás usando una versión libre, la api de twitter solo permite unas [900 llamadas en una ventana de 15 minutos](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits) y ¡Tu archivo tiene 5375 ids! Estoy seguro que, con el tamaño de tu archivo y los intentos que puedes haber hecho mientras elaborabas el código superaste ese límite y la api está rechazando tus peticiones.

Comment: Pues le acabo de cambiar el pass a un continue, a ver que sucede. En cuento a lo de las llamadas, tengo esta linea de código para que se siga ejecutando cuando se pase el límite: api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)

Comment: Imprime el stacktrace: `traceback.print_exc()` dentro del `except`.